# Batch export 1000 .glb files

Tags: python, materials, scripting, shaders, export

I’m trying to batch export 1000 .glb files with a script. the model I want to export uses an image sequence as a image texture that is cycling through 1000 different images. there is also a counter as text object in the scene that is going from #0001 to #1000 (from frame 1 to frame 1000).

When I run the script I can successfully batch export the models at each frame showing the correct number in the text counter but the texture with the image sequence remains the same in each exported file. it will always have the texture of the current frame that is selected in the timeline…

I’m using this script that I found on a forum and modified to my needs to display the model in a correct way while also minimizing the file size of the .glb files:

````
import bpy

# First frame to export
frame_start = 1

# Last frame to export
frame_end = 1000

# Filename
filename = "my-model"

for f in range(frame_start, frame_end + 1):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)
    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
        filepath="%s.f%04d.glb" % (filename, f),
        export_animations=False,
        export_current_frame=True,
        use_visible=True,
        export_materials='EXPORT',
        export_extras=True,
        export_apply=True,
        
        
    )

```
````

Comment: Hello. Is this procedure related to NFTs ?

Comment: Hello! Yes I'm working on a 1k project where i need to export a "glass cube" with a card inside. Everything works out in the viewport or when exporting manually (export, move 1 frame forward, export, and so on)

Comment: Do you have multiple uv maps for each object? How do your material setups look like?

Comment: @Timmethy the cube uses only simple principaled bsdf materials that are exported without problems (glb compatible) the card inside the cube uses a image sequence as texture (uv unwrapped with cube projection) for base color, and also an image sequence with metallic maps for the metallic input. The roughness is set at about .4 and i left all the other parameters alone as they are not supported by the gltf binary format. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Timmethy so to answer your question i unwrapped the uvs once for base color texture and the metallic automatically uses the mapping of the base color, so i didnt have to unwrap the metal map texture.. i hope this makes sense, english is not my first language

Comment: Do you have auto-refresh checked in your image sequence nodes?

Comment: yes here is a pic of my node setup:

https://ibb.co/Chzf8wX